# Creating a Python 2.7 UDF in Amazon Redshift to execute on Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift, geocoding, shapely

I am attempting to create a function on Redshift to be called with SQL. I have looked at the documentation, but I believe how I am writing the code may be an issue.

The purpose of the function is to convert EWKT (Extended Well Known Text https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) to Latitude and Longitude using Python 2.7 package Shapely.

*Shapely package has been installed on Redshift*

I have been successfully run my code using python; however, when I am attempting to create the function to be called in Redshift I am not able to execute the code as expected. I think the methodology of how I am writing the code for redshift is incorrect, but I do not know why - would you please help me to figure this out?

**

- Attempt on Redshift:

**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.latlong(a VARCHAR) RETURNS VARCHAR STABLE as $$

def latlong(z):
  import pandas as pd
  from shapely import wkb
  hexlocation = z['store_geo_location']
  point = wkb.loads(hexlocation, hex=True)
  longitude = point.x
  latitude = point.y
  a = str(latitude) +','+str(longitude)
return(a)

$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

**

- Sample code run in Python:

**

```
from shapely import wkb
import pandas as pd

def f_latlong(z):
    hexlocation = z
    point = wkb.loads(hexlocation, hex=True)
    longitude = point.x
    latitude = point.y
#     return longitude, latitude     
    a = str(latitude) +','+str(longitude)
    return(a)
```

Comment: you don't need `def` line in the UDF definition and all the rows until `return` and including `return` should have the same indentation

Comment: Thank you @AlexYes - 
corrected the indentation and it allowed me to troubleshoot that our devops team didn't provide the necessary permissions specifically for authoring python UDFs in redshift as an explicit permission.